# Parsing a string with a variable length

Tags: mysql

I have an IT background but more involved in PO/PM kind of roles but am picking up on MySQL and have a question. I am trying to parse a text and have troubles with the following.

I have a string consisting of `0000000000XXXXXXXXXX0000000000`. The zero's represent a numeric value (`0-9`) between `5` and `10` positions (it varies) and the `XXXXXXXXXX` represents a a character set of always `10` positions and consisting of `A-Z` an `0-9` but always starts with one letter `A-Z`.

I would like to parse this string down to the `10` characters. Working with trim, locate, mid etc. Seems to be difficult. Can someone help?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and from it what would be the desired result. I think I understand but better to be sure :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing this kind of parsing in your client code (php, python, what have you) but if you absolutely need to do that in MySQL you can create a function similar to this

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION parse_str(val VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
  DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 6;

  IF val IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(val) < 15 THEN 
    RETURN NULL; 
  END IF;

  WHILE pos < 12 DO
    IF SUBSTRING(val, pos, 1) > '9' THEN
      RETURN SUBSTRING(val, pos, 10);
    END IF;

    SET pos = pos + 1;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN NULL;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

You can then use it like so

```sql
SELECT parse_str(val) AS parsed
  FROM table1
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51080d/1) demo

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say whether 'trimming' was to occur on the INSERT or SELECT side.

The DOCS are a great place to look.

[MySQL String Functions - TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Can you improve your question and then let the 'Answerers' know of the edite with a comment below their answer?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.